# jPlayer playlists with a Jquery UI player?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jplayer

I need help figureing out how to get the playlist functionality of the [jPlayer playlist player](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02/?theme=0) incorporated with the [jPlayer with jquery UI](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-07/).

The one piece of functionality I really want is the draggable playhead. It's a total snap to get working and customize using the jQuery UI player for single files, but getting that to work with the playlist version of the player is giving me fits. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Example code for both players here:
http://jsfiddle.net/H2Acx/ and here:  http://jsfiddle.net/8UhCr/

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Well it turns out it's all easier than it looks, unless I'm THAT much of a n00b. I first removed the `setMedia()` call in the default jPlayer instance options, then I just rocked the jPlayerPlaylist instance right after it.</strike>

Well it *actually* turns out that I am indeed THAT much of a n00b.

The default jPlayer instance was ruining the playlist loop (it was just looping the last track of the playlist instead of returning to the first track) and I had to actually integrate the "options" array into the jPlaylist set of options. Then, because the options array was no longer global, I had give more specificity to where the slider functions called for data from the Playlist object...

Here is a working jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mroncetwice/qSaBc

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it be enough to change the cursor to "move" (the cross) when hovering the seek bar, since the jPlayer playhead is already "draggable"?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this to start with:
http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-video/

The jPlayerPlaylist docs are here:
http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/

As for the ASP... There are many possible solutions...